# Why my JSON response is getting prepended with {} &&

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring

> Why my JSON response is getting prepended with **{} &&**

This the JSON response from Firebug:

```
{}
&&
{
    "data": [{
        "activationTime": "1969-12-31T19:00:00.000-0500",
        "description": "Set permanent alert filter ",
        "expirationTime": "1969-12-31T19:00:00.000-0500",
        "hosts": "asdfrd",
        "lastMatchedTime": "2012-09-08T10:34:27.501-0400",
        "matchStrings": "psl[0-9]",
        "matchedTodayCount": "0",
        "nameValuePairs": "",
        "objectId": "212121",
        "state": "PERMANENT",
        "useRegEx": "true",
        "userName": "z111111z"
    }]
}
```

Here is the screenshot of eclipse debugging of the return statement:

[image: Screenshot of return statement]

My controller java code:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

@RequestMapping("/getFilters/{serverName}/")
public JSONObject getFilters(@PathVariable String serverName, HttpServletRequest request) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();     
    List<FilterJSONVO> filteredAlerts = alertFilterService.getAlertFilters(serverName, "");
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.addAll(filteredAlerts);
    json.put("data", jsonArray);
    return json;
}
```

Jquery Call:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#alertfilters').dataTable( {
        "sAjaxSource" : 'getFilters/${sessionScope.monitorServerName}/',
        "columns": [
            { "data": "userName" },
            { "data": "expirationTime" },
            { "data": "lastMatchedTime" },
            { "data": "state" },
            { "data": "matchedTodayCount" },
            { "data": "useRegEx" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

I am using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) with ajax to display Table in my jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix to this would be to use @ResponseBody annotation over the method.
(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody)

Also Add

@RequestMapping("/getFilters/{serverName}/", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")